# Can portulacas be overwintered indoors?

Tags: plant-health, transplanting, overwintering

My [portulaca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portulaca) is growing a clump of short stems at the base of the plant like a [sedum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedum). The sedums use this to grow the next years growth. Could I dig my portulaca up and overwinter it indoors?

**Update:**

The plant did overwinter and grew well the entire next season. However, It didn't produce seed.

Comment: "The sedums use this to grow the next years growth." <-- Can you please explain, as currently I don't fully understand what you mean by that statement...

Comment: Tall Sedums produce rose-like buds at the base of the plant, and these develop into the next years growth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Portulaca grandiflora*](http://www.floridata.com/ref/p/port_gra.cfm) (assuming this is what you're talking about) is an annual, so it seems unlikely that overwintering indoors will work. They reproduce via seed.

You may be able to extend the season long enough for it to flower and set seed while you have it potted indoors. Then you could collect seed and replant outside next spring.

I would note that the seed is fairly cheap (I see 5000 seeds online for $8; you can probably find end-of-season packets in the discount rack right now for $0.99 or less), so it may be best to just buy seed and replant in the spring.

Comment: I like this variety but I don't know the name.

Comment: @jmusser: Unfortunately, you're probably out of luck. You can *try* overwintering it -- there's nothing to lose but your time and a little potting soil.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't heard of people overwintering portulacas, although I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to. The main reason for this is that portulacas are *extremely* easy to grow from seed and grow very well in the northern US, where you are. So I really wouldn't worry about overwintering it and would simply leave it in the ground and start afresh in spring.

Comment: It didn't make any seeds.

Answer (score 2):

I have a beautiful window box of portulaca growing right now that came up from the plants that I never dug out last year!  It was quite a surprise, but they must have gone to seed and wintered well outside.  Of course the plants that came up were not in any orderly fashion, so when they got large enough, I dug up the plant plugs and replanted them in a tidier way.  It looks great now.  Best box I've ever had.  I only have a handful of blooms so far, but heaps of buds ready to pop!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of my fav’s I pluck the dead flowers off and find the seed pod . Dust the tiny seeds on a paper plate and save them in a paper bag for next year . During the Season I put the part I plucked just 1/2 inc into any dirt and it also grows more plants this plant is amazing

Answer (score 1):

My aunt does it very year. She brings some in and puts them in an upstairs window. They root easily and she breaks off pieces and uses these as starters in spring.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to overwinter portulacas in our sunroom, where they get good light all winter.